# convert PEM Certificate or Java Certificate to ASN1 Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, asn.1, cmp

I have a certificate in a PEM file.

I want to construct a `CMPCertificate` from this file. So I have to build an `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate` in order to call `CMPCertificate.getInstance(..)`.

How could I convert a PEM file or a `java.security.cert.Certificate` to `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate`?

Answer (score 0):

After verifying the source code (since the documentation is missing on the subject) the `getInstance` method on `CMPCertificate` accepts `byte[]` type.

This code should work:

```
java.security.cert.X09Certificate cert = generateCertFromPEM(/*...*/);
byte[] encoding = cert.getEncoded();
CMPCertificate cmpCert = CMPCertificate.getInstance(encoding);
```